# Possible to nest an update statement in a case statement?

Tags: sql, airflow

I'm having trouble finding if this type of workflow is allowed. Can you nest an update query inside of a case statement?

I have a large DAG where many tasks funnel into a 'toll gate' task which ensures all upstream tasks have completed before moving on to the next task. Some days, there are certain tasks which will fail due to no data being present. I would like an initial task to identify ahead of time whether or not to run additional downstream tasks based on the success/failure of this task.

One thought is if the initial task fails, to have airflow mark the related downstream tasks as success ahead of time, and skip actually running them. (I cannot set them to skipped because of the nature of our 'toll road' tasks which require all_success for various reasons.

Is it possible to use a case statement in such a way that if data is present, it proceeds as normal, and if it fails, I update the task_instance metadata related downstream tasks as success so that they don't need to be triggered/run? I have some pseudo code below to help explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
select
    case
        when table_a like 'similar_to_table_a' or table_name like 'similar_to_table_b' and DATE_ID = yesterday
            then DATE_ID
        when table_a like 'similar_to_table_a' or table_name like 'similar_to_table_b' and DATE_ID != yesterday
            then UPDATE task_metadata_table
                set task_a status = 'success' --sets a downstream task to success ahead of time, to skip its run
                set task_b status = 'success' --sets a downstream task to success ahead of time, to skip its run
        else OTHER_DATE_ID
    end as WHICH_DATE_ID,
from schema.table_name
where id_number = 1007 and table_name = 'my_table_name'
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  `select` is one type of statement and `update` is another.  In general, SQL does not allow the nesting of statements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks - is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm looking to do here using case statement logic in an update statement instead?